Western comedy with a sheriff that does not want to be a sheriff, and a duel
Western comedy. Likely from the 1960s to early 1980s.
The protagonist is a man that somehow manages to become sheriff in a town. It ends up with him having to duel some badass bandit. I'm not 100% sure about him becoming sheriff, but 99% ;P Believe he did not really want this role.
It is not much I recall from the film, but one distinct thing is that he gets a lot of advice for the duel. Typically that he has to shift to the right (or left) and then bow or do this and that to escape the bullets from the enemy. Believe there also was some advice about the sun and how he should duck and have the wind on this or that side etc.
As he is preparing for (walking to) the duel he is repeating all the advices and believe he is rather confused. He is also very, very scared. The duel was typically set at sunrise (I believe). He might have been small built.
It is more likely from midst 1960s to early 1970s if I recall the colouring, sound, clipping etc. correctly, but I might be wrong.
There might have been some setting where the bandit he is going to duel terrorizes the town. Believe the duel is what it all accumulates to. (In other words not very distinct as westerns are.) Beside this I only recall glimpses that can be from any western / spaghetti film. (Bar fights, people ending up in water bins for horses etc. – but then again I might be mixing in some of those glimpses from other films.)

(I'm trying to forget how much time I've used on this, but:)
I missed a lot on the year, but the duel scene seems to be somewhat accurate, though it was at sunset and not sunrise. It is not however the high-point of the film (I believe). It might be that I did not see the entire film back in the day. It also seems like he might was some sort of secret agent instead of sheriff.
Anyhow: It is the film "The Paleface" from 1948 with Bob Hope as Painless Potter and Jane Russell as Calamity Jane.
From IMDB:

Someone is selling guns to the Indians and in order to find the culprit Calamity Jane and a secret agent go undercover posing as man and wife. When the agent is killed Jane recruits a new husband -- none other than innocent dupe "Painless" Peter Potter, a totally inept dentist and confirmed coward who's main goal is to leave the barbaric west far behind. When their wagon train is attacked by the Indians it's Jane's sharpshooting that saves the day, but she gives the credit to Potter making him an instant hero to the townspeople and instant target to both the Indians and the gunrunners.
Written by A.L.Beneteau <albl@inforamp.net>

 
Clip with the duel. (0:37 +):



